# Help with URI component followed by #

Tags: url

```
http://something.com:80/somedir/index.html?type=test;one=onevalue#nose
```

This is typical URI structure my question is what is "#nose" and how i can use/utilize it as web developer ?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#nose` is the  anchor on the page so if you have an anchor with name `#nose` the page will auto scroll to that anchor once loaded. That form of links can be used to navigate within a single web page.

For Example the following will allow you to make links to the FAQ heading.

```
<a name="faq"><h1>FAQ</h1></a> 


<a href="#faq">Link to the FAQ section</a>
```

Comment: It should be noted that the anchor part is not sent to the server when requesting pages. So you can only use it client-side (JavaScript can see it).